# Accessibility Change in Jaws

Tags: html, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I have an image

```
<a href="#"> <img src="sample.jpg" alt="sample"> </a>
```

which is reading as **LINK GRAPHIC  by JAWS**, I have to make JAWS to read as **Sample Image**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you try to make JAWS read something in particular?
The important part is the information and content your page is giving to your users. What's the purpose of this content?
Only then, verify that screen readers are reading out the information in a correct manner. `a>img` is a link graphic; JAWS is correct.

*Ryan's Notes*

There are two ways to maybe get it like that:

1. Make sure the user is in expert mode with specific settings. *Asking a user to adjust their settings so your site reads nicer, probably won't happen.*
2. Write a JAWS script to interpret `<a><img>` a certain way. _See #1, _

Comment: +1, JAWS reads elements to the user, a link has more semantical value than images, so it says hey you're on a link, oh hey that link has an image in it,  let me read the alt.

Comment: Is there a semantic way to indicate that the image is more important than the link? If the important part of the page is the image, and the fact that it is clickable is secondary, how should the html be constructed to convey this? `<a><img></a>` is a common way to make a clickable image but is there a more appropriate way here?

Comment: @MarkIvey A link is always a very important part of the page, as in "HTML stands for **hypertext** (markup language)" and links allow to navigate through these resources. I can imagine situations where the image is also important but why would the destination of the link be unrelated to the image used inside this link? I mean, describe the destination of the link and in the linked page there'll be more information about this image or else it wouldn't be used in the link. Would need a real test case ;)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your text with **invisible content** markup and **hide img-tag** from JAWS via `aria-hidden`:

```
 <a href="#">
    <div style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">JAWS reads this text</div>

    <img src="sample.jpg" alt="sample" aria-hidden="true">
 </a>
```

More ways to create invisible content can be found here:
https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/